# How to load a popup in the home page?

Tags: magento-2.1, module

I need to show a popup when the store loads and need to ask users to select the city, then only products deliverable to these cities must show.

In the backend, I added some cities to a new attribute 'location'. So in the popup, I need to, maybe query those data in attribute and show them.

Previously I made modules for separate pages. Which has a route id and all? But here I need it on the main page.

Which template, layout should I extend? And all.

Answer (score 3):

I used **magnific popup** you can download source from [Link](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)

> VendorName: Prince
>
> ModuleName: Popup

You can see my full Popup module Here: [Github](https://github.com/prince108/Magento2-PopupManager)

> app/code/Prince/Popup/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Prince_Popup/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"/>
        <css src="Prince_Popup/css/magnific-popup.css"/>   
        <css src="Prince_Popup/css/magnific-animation.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="index.home" template="Prince_Popup::index/popup.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Prince/Popup/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            magnificPopup: 'Prince_Popup/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min',       
            popup: 'Prince_Popup/js/prince_popup'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        magnificPopup: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/Prince/Popup/view/frontend/templates/index/popup.phtml

```
  <div id="popup-content" class="popup-content mfp-with-anim" style="display:none">
      YOUR CONTENT HERE
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['jquery', 'popup' ],
      function ($, popup) {
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: {
                  src: '#popup-content'
                  },
                  type: 'inline',
                  removalDelay: 500
                });
              $('#popup-content').css('display','inline block');
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Getting an error at require.js:166   uncaught error mismatched anonymous define module

Comment: @Mann can you share your requirejs-config.js

Comment: I have pasted what you have given above

Comment: can you do static content deploy. and you can see my full module here: https://github.com/prince108/Magento2-PopupManager

Comment: Yea I have done it.
But I also mentioned another thing, that is I want to load all the cities the store can deliver in that popup. I am trying to to get all the attribute values. I created an attribute 'location' to all the products uploaded by admin.

Reference site for what I want to achieve, [inox movies](https://www.inoxmovies.com/)

Comment: If you have common cities you need to created simple table in database and get data from table or also you can create attribute to get data. for display data in popup you need just past you code at "YOUR CONTENT HERE" of popup.phtml file.

Comment: Ya I can query and get data. Where i need to create block and controllera for frontend. Block/frontend? Am showing in home page should i use specific folder structure?

Comment: You need to create custom module which include popup xml,js,phtml and your block files

Comment: Ya i created a module. Places the phtml, js, xml in view/frontend folder. Am now asking about folder sturucture for blocks and controllers. And any specific page to override( home page) as for layout we used cms_index_index

Comment: Create block and define your block class in cms_index_index. then you can call block functions in popup.phtml. you don't need to override any other page.

Comment: Where do i need to create that block. Folder structure. Vendor/Module/Block/here? Or Vendor/module/block/frontend ? Do i need a controller and other things?

Comment: @PrincePatel I copied all of your code even I used ur Vender n Module names but still it not showing me any popup nor any error

Answer (score 2):

My upper answer is for magnify popup but if you want **default magento 2 modal popup** on homepage you need to create this files

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Cms/js/popup.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\template" name="index.home" template="Magento_Cms::popup.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/templates/popup.phtml

```
<div id="popup-content" class="popup-content" style="display:none">
    YOUR CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/web/js/popup.js

```
require(
    [ 'jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal' ],
    function($, modal) {
        modal({
            autoOpen: true,
            responsive: true,
            clickableOverlay: false,
            modalClass: 'modal-custom',
            title: 'Popup'
        }, $("#popup-content"));
    }
);
```

Comment: Why is the JS in a template file? Wouldn't it be better practice to have JS in a JS file? Markup and logic should be separated IMO.

Comment: @Ben Crook yes you are right but this is just example to explain in short so  new developer can understand easily

Comment: I thought so, but wouldn't it be better to teach new developer how to do it with best practice? Otherwise they'll be learning techniques that aren't good practice

Comment: @Ben Crook Thank you for your suggestion I updated my answer with different js and phtml file